# Laravel - Blade: @include a template with automated "filename-comment"

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I was wondering if there is a way to include a template in a way Blade automatically writes a html-comment with the filename at the beginning of the included template. This could be helpful in a project with lots of templates.

Example:

```
// file 1
<div class="bla">
  @include('folder.subfolder.templatename')
</div>

// file 2 ( folder/subfolder/templatename.blade.php )
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

// resulting file
<div class="bla">
  <!-- folder/subfolder/templatename.blade.php -->
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Imagine a developer needs to implement a feature 2 years later. With the generated comments he will be able to view the sourcecode in the browser and get to know where every temolate is located in the project.

Comment: What does that mean, please clarify your question.

Comment: I simply want to view sourcecode in the browser with the information where the included templates are findeable in the projectfolders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be achieved by extending Blade, though it's a bit hacky. I think laravel should provide a cleaner interface to extend blade.

Well basically what I did, was extending Blade and creating a `@commentinclude` directive. The logic of the include was extracted from [Laravels `compileInclude()` method](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.View.Compilers.BladeCompiler.html#269-282). I just added the comment and a line break in front of it. Since the back references contain some characters of the whole control structure (`('viewname'`) we need to get rid of them first. Also I replaced all dots with `/` characters

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createOpenMatcher('commentinclude');
    $replace = '$1<?php echo "<!-- " . str_replace(["(\'", ".", "\'"], ["", "/", ""], "$2" ) . " -->\r\n" . $__env->make$2, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array(\'__data\', \'__path\')))->render() ?>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $view);
});
```

**Usage example:**

```
@commentinclude('my.view.file')
```

I wonder if someone could provide a cleaner solution to that.